# How can I receive all document objects from a collection in cloud-firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire2

When I try to receive a document from a subcollection I get an object with only the values from the document.

The response looks like this:

```
{
 id: mealDocumentId,
 name: 'Burger',
 imageUrl: 'imgUrl1',
 price: 3, quantity: 1
}
```

Is there a way to receive the object from the entire document?

I was expecting the objects from the documents similar to this:

```
 {
  mealDocumentId1: {
    name: 'Burger1',
    imageUrl: 'imgUrl1',
    price: 1,
    quantity: 1,
  },
  mealDocumentId2: {
    name: 'Burger2',
    imageUrl: 'imgUrl2',
    price: 2,
    quantity: 2,
  },
 }
```

The Code I'm running:

```
 constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  getAllMealDocuments() {
    // this is the path to the subselection meals
    const docRef = this.db.collection('tables').doc('documentId').collection('meals');
    
    // try to get a document object and pass it.
    return  docRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(document => {
      document.map(doc => {
        return new Meal({
          id: doc.payload.doc.id,
          ...(doc.payload.doc.data() as {})
        });
      });
    }));
  }
```

Is there another way to receive all the documents? Preferably like the expected formate?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`documentChanges` stream](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges), which (unlike `valueChanges`) includes the ID of each document in its output.

I'd recommend checking out the AngularFire documentation on [streaming collection data](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#streaming-collection-data) for the types of streams, and the differences between them.

Comment: Hi Frank! Thanks for the quick response. You are right I want to get the id and therefore I called snapshotChanges. My problem is when I loop now through the received data I get back all the values from the document and not the document objects. Do you know if this is the only way to receive documents?

Comment: What do you mean by "the document objects" and "the expected format"? In the code you shared in your update, you can keep `doc`, or extract `doc.id` and `doc.data()`. I'm not sure what other option you are looking for.

Comment: I want to get the documents in a different way back. So now I get objects like {...}, but I want to receive key-value pairs like {documentId: {...value...}}. The documentId should be the key and "all the rest" the value... I hope this is understandable. :)

Comment: That's not an option from the AngularFire API, so you'll have to convert the `documentChanges` stream to the format you want.